# How To Avoid GetComponent on raycasts and collisions

Tags: unity

`GetComponent()` is suggested to not be used so frequently because it can cause a performance impact.

I'm working on a game that needs to check the components of objects that bullets hit. I was looking to get the name of the GameObject and store the component reference in a dictionary but it's very error-prone and also needs dictionary searching.

what is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: I'd say it's worth profiling your dictionary suggestion (but use the collider or game object references or their instance IDs as keys, not the names, that way you can't accidentally get duplicate keys). I'd suspect though that the dictionary solution could be slower. GetComponent (or TryGetComponent which avoids editor allocations) has a cost, but it's not so immense that you need to eliminate absolutely every use of it. If you have dozens of bullet impacts every frame, searching a short list of components on what they hit should not break the bank.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that the performance hit of using `GetComponent()` is going to matter. As they say, "premature optimization is the root of all evil," so unless you are noticing a performance problem in testing or profiling, I would go for the simplest solution: using `GetComponent()` every impact.

However, if there *is* a bottleneck here, a dictionary seems like the only other option. In theory, there is no way to do less work than `GetComponent()` (You have to fetch the references somehow either way). the only way you can optimize is by breaking up the work and doing as much of it ahead of time as possible (caching).

In some cases, you could cut down on the work by only caching the last ~10ish objects that have been hit into a dictionary. By doing this, you could search the smaller dictionary and in an average case only have to load the references once.

In general, when you cache, use an object reference as the key in the dictionary, not the GameObject's name because it uses less memory, and object references are guaranteed to be unique.

You probably would be good not caching and just using `GetComponent()` every time, though.

Comment: I'd be interested in profiling the difference between using object references or `GetInstanceID()` values as keys - it seems plausible that the integer instance ID would have a simpler hash function.